# Animating A Logo With Boolean

Tags: animation, modifiers

[image]
I can't find a way to animate this logo with booleans
so i need this logo to appear from the center with a boolean-like effect

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more intelligent way but here is one:

- Create your P shape from a 64 vertices circe.
- Convert it to Curve.
- Create a plane, it will be your profile shape, don't forget to put vertices close the corner so that it will sharpen the edges.
- Convert it to Curve.
- Now select your P curve, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data*, in *Shape* choose 2D, in *Geometry* choose the plane as the *Bevel Object*, and enable *Fill Caps*.
- The profile appears along the P.
- If you play with the *End* value of the Geometry you'll see that it will progressively fill the P shape. You'll use this value and some keyframes to animate the appearance.
- Duplicate your P shape to build your logo shape.
- Don't forget to *Smooth* the shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the look you are going for. You could have a cylinder that expands so it looks like the logo is appearing from a dot. You could do the same with cubes an ect.

If you want it to grow out from the center following the logo path, look at arrays. Up the number of units to extend the length. Note: it must have a path to follow so if you could make some sort of vertex string that would help. This could be done manually or using a method like reverse skinning. I have no clue on how to easily ‘reverse skin’ but I am sure someone could help. You can then mirror it from the center for symmetry.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB